# Admin cannot access path even after adding - Web.config <allow roles="Admin"/>

Tags: c#

Config file:

```
<location path="reports.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I am having problems with authentication on my web.config, I have denied all users the problem is the admin cannot also access the form although I have it exempted

Comment: What kind of error or issue you are facing while authenticating with Admin role. From code it seems that everything is fine.

Comment: The admin cannot also access the path

Comment: <location path="reports.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location> as you see i have location path, but the admin cannot also access the said path, now no one access my admin panel

Comment: There are two cases why your authorization is not working.

1. **Sequence of allow and deny**. Authorization done from top to bottom so always keep authorized roles and users on top of deny. Here your code is fine.

2. **Please check role** for accessing `reports.aspx` file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<location path="reports.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <add accessType="Allow" users="*" roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```